# Android WebRTC implementaion - very low volume

Tags: android, webrtc-android

I have implement an option of Video Conference on my application using the following example:
https://github.com/androidthings/sample-videoRTC

basically is is working very well but i have one major issue. the sreaming audio volume is very very low even when i put the maximum volume on my device.

I have tried to check if there is any parameter that can define the audio volume but is was not able to find such parameters beside the AudioBitRate(=32) and the AudioCodec=("OPUS").

These are the parameters that is am using for creating the peerConnection:

```
    peerConnectionParameters =
            new PeerConnectionClient.PeerConnectionParameters(true,
                    false,
                    false,
                    videoWidth,
                    videoHeight,
                    0,
                    Integer.parseInt(getString(R.string.pref_maxvideobitratevalue_default)),
                    getString(R.string.pref_videocodec_default),
                    true,
                    false,
                    Integer.parseInt(getString(R.string.pref_startaudiobitratevalue_default)),
                    getString(R.string.pref_audiocodec_default),
                    false,
                    false,
                    false,
                    false,
                    false,
                    false,
                    false,
                    false,
                    null);
```

Is anyone have some idea how can I improve the audio volume?

Ihave tried to replace the default Audio Codec but the result was the same low vloume.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After many check and investigation i have found the problem. i am answering it here if someone else will have the same problem.

i have notice that the voice is not routed to the speaker but to the ear cap...so i add the bellow code to turn on the speaker and the problem has solved !

```
    audioManager = (AudioManager) this.activity.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
    audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
```

To answer the question where i put the code, i have actually add a new icon to give the user to switch between headset and speaker.

here is the full code:

```
    toggleSpeakerHeadset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (speakerOn) {
                setHeadsetOn();
            } else {
                setSpeakerOn();
            }
        }
    });

private void setSpeakerOn() {
    speakerOn = true;
    toggleSpeakerHeadset.setImageResource(R.drawable.headset);
    audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
    audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
}

private void setHeadsetOn() {
    speakerOn = false;
    toggleSpeakerHeadset.setImageResource(R.drawable.speaker);
    audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
    audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem with my app. I wanted to ask where should i place this code?

Comment: it should placed after asking permission and before initiating a call