# How to increase the sound Volume Output in Webrtc

Tags: java, android, webrtc, webrtc-android

Am working on a webrtc android application and everything is working fine except two things...
which are;

1. switching the default sound output device from the Earpiece to Speaker and vice versa..
   I have tried to use the code below from [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56212048/android-webrtc-implementaion-very-low-volume) but they are not working

```
audioManager = (AudioManager) this.activity.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
```

2. And improving the video performance, there is a lot of lagging in the video streams where even the stream hangs a lot. if there is any one who can help me on this too thanks a lot.
   Below is my peerConnection configs

```java
String fieldTrials = (PeerConnectionFactory.VIDEO_FRAME_EMIT_TRIAL + "/" + PeerConnectionFactory.TRIAL_ENABLED + "/");
PeerConnectionFactory.InitializationOptions initializationOptions =
                PeerConnectionFactory.InitializationOptions.builder(this)
                        .setFieldTrials(fieldTrials)
                        .createInitializationOptions();
PeerConnectionFactory.initialize(initializationOptions);

//Create a new PeerConnectionFactory instance - using Hardware encoder and decoder.
PeerConnectionFactory.Options options = new PeerConnectionFactory.Options();
DefaultVideoEncoderFactory defaultVideoEncoderFactory = new DefaultVideoEncoderFactory(
                rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext(),  /* enableIntelVp8Encoder */true,  /* enableH264HighProfile */true);
DefaultVideoDecoderFactory defaultVideoDecoderFactory = new DefaultVideoDecoderFactory(rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext());

peerConnectionFactory = PeerConnectionFactory.builder()
                .setOptions(options)
                .setVideoEncoderFactory(defaultVideoEncoderFactory)
                .setVideoDecoderFactory(defaultVideoDecoderFactory)
                .createPeerConnectionFactory();
```

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56262619/8637561

Comment: @VincenzoNinni thanks, for your response but I tried the solution in that thread and it didn't work for me I even indicated it in the question

Comment: what does it means it is not working? what are the actual results? can you share your  code?

Answer (score 1):

Need add this permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
```